# PDF to JPG local conversion

Tags: pdf, converters, jpeg

I'm looking for a solution that will allow users to convert PDF files possibly of multiple pages into JPGs. The solution must be local, online solutions are a no go due to security issues and it must be as ridiculously simple as possible so non IT types can use it easily. Licensing is not an issue but would prefer for it to be GPL. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be easy to use or also easy to install?

Comment: I will be installing it myself so that is not an issue, just easy to use.

Comment: What operating system? For Mac OS X you could use the accepted answer here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/best-way-to-convert-multipage-pdf-to-separate-jpgs

Comment: Thanks but my users are all using Win7 32bit. Should have made that clear earlier.

Comment: This question is off-topic here since it is not related to programming, it might be better for you to ask it in superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/), with a command line like

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=page%02d.jpg -r150 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH file.pdf
```

where 150 is the resolution in dots per inch. You could wrap this in some script that presents a nicer user interface.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at Ghostscript. I would prefer not to have to do any programming work myself as it would be chargeable and I don't have the time. I was aiming for just a quick install that does the converstion with minimum fuss.

Comment: This *is* a site for programming questions, you know.